# Why we have to do a regular commit immediately after conflicts resolved in Git?

Tags: git, merge, conflict

Why we have to do a regular commit immediately after conflicts resolved in Git?

What if I modify some other files after conflicts resolved, then commit them together?

What is the difference?

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what you are asking. Are you asking why the command to tell Git that you're finished resolving the conflicts doesn't have a different name like `git resolved` rather that the same `git commit` that you also use to make normal single-parent commits?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "difference".

If a merge ends up with one or more conflicts it merges as much as possible and then halts, informing you about these conflicts.

It is then your task to commit the final merge commit once you've resolved those conflicts.

The reason for this is that the merge conflict resolution step is manually performed by invoking other git commands, external conflict resolution tools, inspecting the files manually and visually, etc. It's not an interactive process and as such git doesn't hang around waiting for you to complete resolving the conflicts before it commits as normal. It simply says "I stop here, commit when you're done".

If, in addition to resolving these conflicts, you change the files on disk further and adds those changes and then commit, it will just commit everything together. There's nothing special about this.

A merge commit is like any other regular commit except that it has (usually) two parents instead of one, other than that it is an entirely regular commit with all the bells and whistles. The fact that it was a merge operation performed by git that prepared all the changes the commit introduced is just a detail, you can construct a merge commit yourself 100% manually by staging the right changes and telling git to commit with two parents.

As such, the difference between you modifying the files further vs. you don't do this is that the merge will contain more changes vs. only what git + the conflict resolution added.

Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Sorry to comment here but not sure how tag your name in the comment. Your close my question and the related answer doesn't say how fix the Deserealize part.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a commit because the last step of a merge is a (usually behind-the-scenes) commit, and when there are conflicts git leaves that step out.  So rather than create a new command or sub-command for this situation, it was decided to just let you finish the last step after you'd tidied up the index.

You *can* make changes other than conflict resolutions.  Sometimes this is necessary to properly resolve the conflict.  It wouldn't be possible for git to "know" if the changes you make are truly needed for conflict resolution.  I suppose it *could* detect changes that weren't inside conflict markers and issue a warning, but a hard stop would prevent legitimate resolutions in some conflict scenarios and it doesn't seem worth the extra effort that would be involved for a warning.  So instead the developer is trusted to do what they should do.

Besides, did you know that you can specifically *tell* git not to commit the merge, so that you can edit the merge result (even though there were no conflicts) before committing it?  You probably shouldn't, but you can.

Be aware that making changes that aren't actual conflict resolution in a merge may have negative effects down the road, because those changes are somewhat "hidden" in the merge commit, such that you have to know to look for them.

But git is a powerful tool, and generally it expects you to know how to use that power.  The ability to commit the content you want in commits with the parent(s) you want is part of that power.